# Display loading icon for the actual duration of the document load time?

Tags: jquery, load, icons, loading

using jQuery load or something similar, can you nest a function inside the .load() function and display a loading icon for the actual load-time of the file?

I've done things similar but I've never confirmed with myself that this was possible

Answer (score 1):

You sure can, you can set a loading image to display just before you do the load - then hide the loading image when the callback function is executed...

```
$('#loadingImage').fadeIn();

$('#result').load('mysite/mypage', function() {
   // loading complete - callback called
   $('#loadingImage').hide();
});
```

Comment: gosh, thanks - so simple. thats like exactly the code I'm using I just didn't know if what I was trying to do was acurate

Comment: thats the great thing about jQuery - simples! mark as answer please :)

Answer (score 0):

You can show the icon, issue the request, then use the completion callback of the [`load`](http://api.jquery.com/load) function to hide the icon. That's great for one specific load call.

Alternatively, you can use [`ajaxStart`](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxStart/) and [`ajaxStop`](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxStop/) to do it for *any* request you issue on the page at any time. `ajaxStart` is triggered when an ajax request is started and there isn't any other currently running; `ajaxStop` is triggered when an ajax request completes and there are none others outstanding.

So you could have an element with the `id` "loading" which is initially hidden, and do this:

```
$("#loading")
    .ajaxStart(function() { $(this).fadeIn();  })
    .ajaxStop( function() { $(this).fadeOut(); });
```

See the linked docs for details.